# set position of programmatically created imageview android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am just trying to position my imageView on desired place on screen, but for some reason, picture is always a little bit off, it is not in the right place. For example, this is my code if I want it to put in the middle of the screen.

Getting the screen size:

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Getting the picture size:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car1, o);
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
```

Creating and positioning imageView:

```
    image = new ImageView(this);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.car1);
    image.setId(1);


    params.setMargins((width/2)-w,(height/2)-h, 0, 0);


    ((ViewGroup) mainLayout).addView(image, params);
```

My imageView is not on the middle of the screen and I don't know why, any help? I took middle of the screen as an example; I need various positions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the ImageView's anchor point is the middle of the image or the top left corner. If it is the top left corner, you would need to modify your margin calculation:

```
params.setMargins((width-w)/2,(height-h)/2, 0, 0);
```